# Unable to to host a Rails 4 application with external MongoDB provider on OpenShift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, openshift

I'm unable to host a **Rails 4** application that uses **Mongoid** together with an external MongoDB database on OpenShift Online.

The deployment process looks fine, but when I try to access the application I get the following error:

```
method=GET path=/ format=html controller=cms/pages action=index status=500 error='ActionView::Template::Error:Permission denied - bind(2)' duration=1269.29
ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - bind(2)):
    1: <div class="container <%= defined?(container_id) ? container_id : '' %>">
    2:     <div class="dynamic-grid__container">
    3:       <%= yield %>
    4:     </div>
    5: </div>
  app/views/cms/pages/index.html.erb:34:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_cms_pages_index_html_erb__3332757160159689462_59144880'
  app/views/templates/_dynamic_grid.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_templates__dynamic_grid_html_erb__483337236520907652_58770660'
  app/views/cms/pages/index.html.erb:31:in `block in _app_views_cms_pages_index_html_erb__3332757160159689462_59144880'
  app/views/cms/pages/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_cms_pages_index_html_erb__
```

After doing some research, it looks that this error is related to a Bug in OpenShift that prevents the Mongoid Gem to resolve a DNS hostname by binding 0.0.0.0 on a random UDP port.
Am I correct with this assumption?

See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1081206 and the Trello https://trello.com/c/RnuyxlP7/175-fix-the-case-when-ruby-applications-want-to-bind-on-random-udp-port-using-0-0-0-0

This makes OpenShift totally unusable with Rails and Mongoid. 
I wonder why this issue persists for such a long time now.

Can I work around this issue somehow for now?

### UPDATE:

The actual issue is that an external DB connection configured via an environment variable that is used inside the mongoid.yml, e.g.,

```
rhc set-env MONGO_URL=mongodb://username:pass@ds059938.mongolab.com:59938/dbname
```

is somehow not accessible. When I use an OpenShift MongoDB gear inside the local network, e.g. 127.x.x.x it works as expected.

For me, the trace still looks related to the bug:

```
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:647:in `bind'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:647:in `bind_random_port'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:783:in `initialize'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:552:in `new'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:552:in `make_udp_requester'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:510:in `each_resource'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:406:in `each_address'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:115:in `block in each_address'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:114:in `each'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:114:in `each_address'
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/resolv.rb:57:in `each_address'
vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/moped-2.0.0.beta6/lib/moped/address.rb:50:in `block in resolve'
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue only exists for scalable applications. If you do run through this in a non-scalable application, everything should work just fine. Check out a blog I wrote on the subject here https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-host-ruby-on-rails-4-apps-on-openshift

Comment: Hm, I'm stuck here. The application deploys without errors, but just doesn't run. I tried several other ideas to find potential problems, but the error message ```ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - bind(2))```should indicate it's related to some network issue?! I was able to deploy the exact same app to other PaaS vendors without problems. Any ideas where I can investigate any further?

Comment: The permission denied - bind(2) means that something (framework or DB) is trying to bind to an address that's not allowed. Did you use the Rails 4 quickstart or did you create a DIY cartridge app?

Comment: I created a ruby 2 application via ```rhc create myapp ruby-2.0``` and merged my app code in the resulting repository. Should be equivalent to your referenced tutorial. As further information - the app is uses Rails, Mongodb and Redis. I already deactivated Redis caching, tho.

Comment: Further debugging: I'm using Mongolab as external DB provider via an environment variable inside the OpenShift gear that configures the connection inside the mongoid.yml (Port 59938). It looks like this is blocked by the gear. This is however common practise for other PaaS, how can I deal with this?

Comment: For me, it still looks related to the bug...see the full stack trace: https://gist.github.com/stefan-kolb/11df78702923c22928e1